# decimalFormat.format() error

Tags: android, kotlin

The decimalFormat declaration is as follows :

```
private var decimalFormat: DecimalFormat? = null 
decimalFormat = DecimalFormat("#.##########")
```

The values that are to be passed to format() method are :

```
private var valueOne= java.lang.Double.NaN
private var valueTwo: Double = 0.toDouble()
```

I am trying to make a calculator app, and the error that I get is in the operator buttons when I pass    *valueOne*    to the    *format()*    method :

```
 binding!!.buttonAdd.setOnClickListener {
        computeCalculation()
        CURRENT_ACTION = ADDITION
        binding!!.infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "+")
        binding!!.editText.setText(null)
    }

    binding!!.buttonSubtract.setOnClickListener {
        computeCalculation()
        CURRENT_ACTION = SUBTRACTION
        binding!!.infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "-")
        binding!!.editText.setText(null)
    }

    binding!!.buttonMultiply.setOnClickListener {
        computeCalculation()
        CURRENT_ACTION = MULTIPLICATION
        binding!!.infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "*")
        binding!!.editText.setText(null)
    }

    binding!!.buttonDivide.setOnClickListener {
        computeCalculation()
        CURRENT_ACTION = DIVISION
        binding!!.infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "/")
        binding!!.editText.setText(null)
    }

    binding!!.buttonEqual.setOnClickListener {
        computeCalculation()
        binding!!.infoTextView.text = binding!!.infoTextView.text.toString() +
                decimalFormat.format(valueTwo) + " = " + decimalFormat.format(valueOne)
        valueOne = java.lang.Double.NaN
        CURRENT_ACTION = '0'
    }
```

The error that I get is :

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public final fun format(obj: Any!): String! defined in 
java.text.DecimalFormat
public final fun format(number: Double): String! defined in 
java.text.DecimalFormat
public final fun format(number: Long): String! defined in 
java.text.DecimalFormat
```

The complete code for the onCreate() method is given below :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)

    decimalFormat = DecimalFormat("#.##########")

    binding?.buttonDot?.setOnClickListener { binding?.editText?.setText((binding as ActivityMainBinding).editText.text.toString() + ".") }

    binding?.buttonZero?.setOnClickListener { binding?.editText?.setText((binding as ActivityMainBinding).editText.text.toString() + "0") }

    binding?.buttonOne?.setOnClickListener { binding?.editText?.setText((binding as ActivityMainBinding).editText.text.toString() + "1") }

    binding?.buttonTwo?.setOnClickListener { binding?.editText?.setText((binding as ActivityMainBinding).editText.text.toString() + "2") }

    binding?.buttonThree?.setOnClickListener { binding?.editText?.setText((binding as ActivityMainBinding).editText.text.toString() + "3") }

    binding?.buttonFour?.setOnClickListener { binding?.editText?.setText((binding as ActivityMainBinding).editText.text.toString() + "4") }

    binding?.buttonFive?.setOnClickListener { binding?.editText?.setText((binding as ActivityMainBinding).editText.text.toString() + "5") }

    binding?.buttonSix?.setOnClickListener { binding?.editText?.setText((binding as ActivityMainBinding).editText.text.toString() + "6") }

    binding?.buttonSeven?.setOnClickListener { binding?.editText?.setText((binding as ActivityMainBinding).editText.text.toString() + "7") }

    binding?.buttonEight?.setOnClickListener { binding?.editText?.setText((binding as ActivityMainBinding).editText.text.toString() + "8") }

    binding?.buttonNine?.setOnClickListener { binding?.editText?.setText((binding as ActivityMainBinding).editText.text.toString() + "9") }

    binding!!.buttonAdd.setOnClickListener {
        computeCalculation()
        CURRENT_ACTION = ADDITION
        binding!!.infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "+")
        binding!!.editText.setText(null)
    }

    binding!!.buttonSubtract.setOnClickListener {
        computeCalculation()
        CURRENT_ACTION = SUBTRACTION
        binding!!.infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "-")
        binding!!.editText.setText(null)
    }

    binding!!.buttonMultiply.setOnClickListener {
        computeCalculation()
        CURRENT_ACTION = MULTIPLICATION
        binding!!.infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "*")
        binding!!.editText.setText(null)
    }

    binding!!.buttonDivide.setOnClickListener {
        computeCalculation()
        CURRENT_ACTION = DIVISION
        binding!!.infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "/")
        binding!!.editText.setText(null)
    }

    binding!!.buttonEqual.setOnClickListener {
        computeCalculation()
        binding!!.infoTextView.text = binding!!.infoTextView.text.toString() +
                decimalFormat.format(valueTwo) + " = " + decimalFormat.format(valueOne)
        valueOne = java.lang.Double.NaN
        CURRENT_ACTION = '0'
    }

    binding!!.buttonClear.setOnClickListener {
        if (binding!!.editText.text.length > 0) {
            val currentText = binding!!.editText.text
            binding!!.editText.setText(currentText.subSequence(0, currentText.length - 1))
        } else {
            valueOne = java.lang.Double.NaN
            valueTwo = java.lang.Double.NaN
            binding!!.editText.setText("")
            binding!!.infoTextView.text = ""
        }
    }

}
```

Please help me solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

See DecimalFormat doc here [DecimalFormat doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

your usage of this class is wrong, and the error message is clear.
The method format(obj: Any!) format(number: Double) format(number: Long) is not defined.

Your should use format(double number, StringBuffer result, FieldPosition fieldPosition)